# External tool coding required for Parasoft

Tags: parasoft

I know this is not as per guidelines, but i do need some help in parasoft extendaion tool coding part. I have all the logic that is required but dont know how to start

1 . I have 8 digit     "50000002"

2 . I have another 8 digit checksum code     "12121212"

3 . Now multiply each number with the 8 digit checksum code

5 0 0 0 0 0 0 2

1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2

==================

(5*1)(0*2)(0*1).....(2*2)

==================

4 . Now take the multiples and check if it is greater than equal  or less than 9. if the multiples is less than 9, the value should be the number of multiple

> For e.g. Last digit was 2*2 = 4 and 4 > 9 is false : so value would be 4

If it is greater then it that number should be subtracted by 9

> For e.g. 9*2 = 18 and 18 > 9 is true : so the value would be 18-9 = 9

5 . Then we need to add all the number got from step 4 and use the below formuale

> 10-MOD(SUM(Step4_value),10)

if the value from the above formula is equal to 10 then it should give number 0 or else the value will the same of the formula.

**EDITED**

Comment: Do you mean Extension Tool from Parasoft SOAtest? If yes what help do you need? Do you expect help with writing such code? You have algorithm, so you have to "create" a code. Did you try? Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: External Tool from Parasoft SOAtest requires separate application to execute.With such requirement, you have to create executable or jar to execute from External Tool. Extension Tool from SOAtest allows you to execute code inside tool (like Java, JavaScript, Jython, and others supported scripting options)

Comment: Hi @szmyru-IrekSz. I need help in writing the code in Jython for **Extenstion Tool**. Currently what i did is i wrote a Vbscript file which is been executed from **External Tool**, and the output from the Vbscript file is saved in a txt file which later read from **Extenstion**

Comment: Use Jython or JavaScript instead of Vbscript to run it in Extension Tool. There is no support for Vbscript in SOAtest.

Comment: @szmyru-IrekSz. This is where i need help, i have executed a vbscript with help of an External tool. I need to skip this part and I need help in Jython or java script